# web3.py locally signed transaction rejected because of invalid nonce

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py, raw-transaction, nonce

I'm trying to sign locally a transaction to a smart contract method using web3.py. 
I'm using ganache and there is one interesting issue when I send a transaction as the contract deployer everything is OK. Whenever I call the contract from a different address I get a message `"the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 11 tx has nonce of: 0"` and a RPC error is thrown.

It's my code:

```
from web3 import Web3

import json
import asyncio


class Client:
    def __init__(self, provider, contract_address, private_key):
       self.web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider))
       with open("abi.json") as abi_file:
           abi = json.load(abi_file)
       self.contract_instance = self.web3.eth.contract(
           address=contract_address, abi=abi)
       self.account = self.web3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key)

    async def asset_emit(self, to_address, meta):
       raw_tx = self.contract_instance.functions.assign(to_address, meta).buildTransaction({
        'nonce': self.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.account._address)
    })

       signed_tx = self.web3.eth.account.signTransaction(
        raw_tx, private_key=self.account._privateKey)

       sent_tx = self.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

       return Web3.toHex(sent_tx)


provider = "http://localhost:7545"
contract_address = "0x1a6bBC4F4759053A3EAc90ECF2b8458c26C6420f"
private_keys = [
"0a62d720053110c9ece23ca0b1aef887dd8107e246e8ed646cadd8f86c5cff72",
"4867ce02e3d309962375b368065623f9ff33adbf50b754f15f9f0dab3b5311b8",
"0dc0af03cf395fe7d617ca4c2951d4240c4fdcc67cf78b3e0a5e666662b543b6",
"5cf0c6d817044434fc94ca40a2f8434658195575d19d0732034edbc4e63709b6",
"75093f0ec4bdc9e4b442bfd19a0550c939de81d287bcedeca46e6048b19b983d",
"0fd5c5c6e2b641741c59952b78cb7b979a7564c1c7926cc6fbc77d96f5c3a38e"
]


async def test():
for i in range(0, len(private_keys)):
    try:
        client = Client(provider, contract_address, private_keys[i])
        await gts_sdk.asset_emit(
            "0x91F64E8D876690b617B252445790B5e3fCc9322D", "0x10")
        print(True)
    except:
        print(False)
await client.asset_emit(
    "0x91F64E8D876690b617B252445790B5e3fCc9322D", "0x10")


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [
asyncio.ensure_future(test())
]

event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
event_loop.close()
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem I did not define 'from' property in the raw_tx dictionary object so web3 was substituting it with accounts[0] it means the address which deployed the contract. 
it's how the object should look like:

```
raw_tx = self.contract_instance.functions.assign(to_address, meta).buildTransaction({
        'from': self.account._address,
        'nonce': self.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.account._address)
    })
```

Comment: Mate, if that work I will love you